# Unable to separate semi-colon separated line awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to do the following:

1. Read a file line by line.
2. Each line has the following structure: `field1;field2;field3`
3. Use `awk` to separate each of these fields and then process each of these fields further

The snippet of code I have is:

```
while read l
do
n=`echo ${l} | awk --field-separator=";" '{print NF}'`
field1=`echo ${l} | awk --field-separator=";" '{print $1}'`
field2=`echo ${l} | awk --field-separator=";" '{print $2}'`
field3=`echo ${l} | awk --field-separator=";" '{print $3}'`
echo ${n} ${field1} ${field2} ${field3} 
done < temp
```

Where temp contains only the following line:

```
xx;yy;zz
```

The answer I get on the command line is:

```
1 xx;yy;zz
```

I am not sure I understand this output. Any explanations would be nice, given that it does work for other files. I am working on a Mac while this code uses `awk` within a `bash` script.

Comment: I got the expected output: `3 xx yy zz` Which version of `awk` are you using?

Comment: `awk --version` results in "awk version 20070501"

Comment: I have `GNU Awk 3.1.8`. Try to execute the script on a machine with `gawk 3`  to see if it is really a version problem

Comment: Why not use `awk` for the whole process and get rid of the shell `while` loop? `awk --field-separator=';' '{print NF, $1, $2, $3}' foo.txt`

Comment: Seems unlikely that `awk` would return `1` for `NF` and still be able to find the **three** fields.

Comment: @mbratch: Like I said, I need each of these fields for some further processing. Hence the need to process them line by line.

Comment: @devnull: I think it finds only one field: xx;yy;zz and not xx yy zz

Comment: Try `-F';'` instead of `--field-separator=';'`

Comment: Never use the letter el (`l`) as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number one (`1`) and so obfuscates your code. Ditto for capital letter oh (`O`) vs number zero (`0`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your awk has no idea what `--field-separator=";"` means so when you do this:

```
awk --field-separator=";" '{print $1}'
```

your awk is still using the default FS of a space, and so $1 contains your whole input line while $2 and $3 are empty. Use `-F';'` to set the FS.

You are WAY, WAY off the mark in how to write the script you want. If you tell us more about what "process each field" is, we can help you.

Comment: Why so condescending? `--field-separator=";"` works on my machine and is not the problem. And the awk manpage even specifies it: `-F fs or --field-separator fs, Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).`
As for being way off the mark: I agree, but maybe you could have provided a better solution, as some of the other people did.

Comment: What's condescending about it? It doesn't matter what YOUR awk does or doesn't accept, that was the problem the OP was having, if you're suggesting that a shell loop of any kind as the other answers suggest is a better solution then you too are way off the mark (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)), and I can't offer a better solution since the OP hasn't fully described the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Why awk when you can do it in pure bash?

```
while IFS=';' read -r field1 field2 field3; do
    echo "Field1: $field1"
    echo "Field2: $field2"
    echo "Field3: $field3"
done < file.txt
```

Or if you don't know the field count:

```
while IFS=';' read -ra fields; do        
    echo "Number of fields: ${#fields[@]}"
    echo "Field1 ${fields[0]}"
done < file.txt
```

Comment: No need to pass as it to another variable like `line`. You could just do `while IFS=';' read -ra fields`.

Comment: Regarding `Why awk when you can do it in pure bash?` - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @EdMorton I think you're missing the point entirely. In most cases, there's no benefit in processing the lines unless you actually do something with them. Which is why we always loop over the lines in bash at some point. You can come up with something using `xargs`, but then I'd like to see how that is in any way more readable.

Comment: No, I'm not missing the point at all. You seem to be assuming the OP wants to call some shell command with values from the input file while I'm assuming that they  want to further manipulate them as text, e.g. rearranging them, averaging values, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a bug with your awk. Try other formats like these:

```
while read l
do
    n=`echo "${l}" | awk -F\; '{print NF}'`
    field1=`echo "${l}" | awk -F\; '{print $1}'`
    field2=`echo "${l}" | awk -F\; '{print $2}'`
    field3=`echo "${l}" | awk -F\; '{print $3}'`
    echo "${n} ${field1} ${field2} ${field3}"
done < temp
```

Or

```
while read l
do
    n=`echo "${l}" | awk -v 'FS=;' '{print NF}'`
    field1=`echo "${l}" | awk -v 'FS=;' '{print $1}'`
    field2=`echo "${l}" | awk -v 'FS=;' '{print $2}'`
    field3=`echo "${l}" | awk -v 'FS=;' '{print $3}'`
    echo "${n} ${field1} ${field2} ${field3}"
done < temp
```

Or

```
while read l
do
    n=`echo "${l}" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}{print NF}'`
    field1=`echo "${l}" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}{print $1}'`
    field2=`echo "${l}" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}{print $2}'`
    field3=`echo "${l}" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}{print $3}'`
    echo "${n} ${field1} ${field2} ${field3}"
done < temp
```

Try other awks like `mawk` or `nawk` as well.

Comment: It's not a bug with his awk, it's a feature. Or maybe lack of a feature (`--field-separator`) would be more accurate.

Comment: @EdMorton But wouldn't awk show an error message if the option is not accepted? If the feature is recognized but not yet working the way it should then I think it's a bug.

Comment: awk --foo is a valid awk script for some awks (I'm not sure which ones support long options - GNU does but what else?). Similarly with awk --field-separator - it's decrementing the variable named field and subtracting the value of the variable named separator from it or teating it as 2 separate statements.